# Sorting array for every child coming after parent

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, parent-child

I have an array like that:

```
<?php
array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'parent_id' => null
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'parent_id' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'parent_id' => null
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'parent_id' => 2
    )
)
```

I need to sort it to every child comes after it's immediate parent. So, ID 4 item should come right after ID 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Can one parent have more than one child?  If so, how does this get resolved?

Comment: What is the priority for null parents?  Are they sorted above the children?  i.e. 1=>null,3=>null,2=>1,4=>2.  Or are the nulls expected after the children?  i.e. 1=>null,2=>1,4=>2,3=>null

Comment: Sure it can. I'm building a UL LI list from this array but i dont want to use recursive functions, so if childs come after parent, it will be more easy.

Comment: NULL's are root nodes. so they should come first.

Comment: when you compare NULL with other numbers it always come first, Try my solution in answers.

Comment: I was waiting 5 minutes to pass to accept your solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working solution** : PHP has user define sorting function [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) I have used this to sort your array.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'parent_id' => null
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'parent_id' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'parent_id' => null
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'parent_id' => 2
    )
);



function cmp($a, $b) {    
    if ($a['parent_id'] == $b['parent_id']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['parent_id'] < $b['parent_id']) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($data, 'cmp');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: what if parent_id is GUID?

Answer (score 3):

This working solution works with [array_multisort()](http://php.net/array_multisort).

Try with:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'parent_id' => null
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'parent_id' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'parent_id' => null
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'parent_id' => 2
    )
);

$parent_ids = array();
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $parent_ids[]  = $item['parent_id'];
}

array_multisort($parent_ids, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

If you want `null` values to be at the end replace that `foreach` with:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if (is_null($item['parent_id'])) {
        $item['parent_id'] = PHP_INT_SIZE;
    }
    $parent_ids[]  = $item['parent_id'];
}
```

See result with: `print_r($data);`.

Comment: Yep. Multisort for the win.